# how to use sort function inside a map function ? i want to sort the file name in ascending order

Tags: reactjs

This part of the code is displaying the filename. And i want to sort the filename now in ascending order how to do that

```
{
                    allFileVersions.map((eachVersion)=> {
                        return(
                            <div className = "d-flex">
                                <div className = "">version:</div>
                                <div className = "">{eachVersion.FileName}</div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })    
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sort the files basis the FileName before generating the nodes using map.

```
 allFileVersions.sort((a,b) => a.FileName.localeCompare(b.FileName));

 {
   allFileVersions.map((eachVersion)=> {
      return(
        <div className = "d-flex">
          <div className = "">version:</div>
          <div className = "">{eachVersion.FileName}</div>
        </div>
      );
    })    
 }
```

Comment: do i have to save that in variable

Comment: @AbhishekRoy not required. Array.sort sorts the array inplace. Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort for more details.